# undefined index: name in XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, xampp

This is the first page: Index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Index</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="Index" action="Result.php" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off"><br><br> 1. I identify my gender as... <br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="others">Others<br><br>
    <INPUT Type="submit" Value="Proceed" Onclick="Index.action='Test2.php'; return true;">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

This is the second page: Test2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test2</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="Result.php" method="POST">
    2. What is your age?<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="14years">Under 14 years old<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="15years">15-24 years old<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="25years">25-59 years old<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="60years">60-74 years old<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="75years">Above 75 years old<br><br><br><br>
    <INPUT Type="submit" Value="Proceed" Onclick="Index.action='Test3.php'; return true;">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

This is the third page: Test3.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test3</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="Result.php" method="POST">
    3. Please specify your ethnicity (race)<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="race" value="chinese">Chinese<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="race" value="malay">Malay<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="race" value="indian">Indian<br> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="race" value="others">Others<br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

This is the last page: Result.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Result</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Welcome!
  <?php echo $_POST["username"]; ?><br>
  <?php
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
if ($gender == "others")
    echo "<font size='5'>You are not normal</font><br><br>";
else
    echo "<font size='5'>You are normal</font><br><br>";

$age = $_POST['age'];
if (($age == "60years") || ($age == "75years"))
    echo "<font size='5'>You are old man</font><br><br>";
else
    echo "<font size='5'>You are young man</font><br><br>";

$race = $_POST['race'];
if ($race == "others")
    echo "<font size='5'>You are from other race</font><br><br>";
else
    echo "<font size='5'>You are from one of three races</font><br><br>";
?>
</body>

</html>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

So, This is the four pages do: Index.php -> Test2.php -> Test3.php -> Result.php where Result.php displays the values of the textbox and radio buttons (if...else). But when I run the pages: Index.php go to Test2.php and just skip the Test3.php and direct go to Result.php. And in Reslt.php, I got this outcome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdCPe.png)

So, what should I do? I searched over the Internet and tried different solutions out there but couldn't work as I expected. After that, I discovered that there maybe has some problems with the  button. So, again I go to Internet to find proper solution but failed to do so. Now I have no idea how to do that. Some explanations with code will be a big help for me. Thanks ;)

Comment: do you want to allow people to skip steps?

Comment: Note, you should only use the code snippet button for JS, HTML and CSS and if running the code snippet is relevant to the question. Otherwise use the code sample button.

Comment: smith, no I do not want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the value you need on every page,and post them to the next page.

For example,in `test2.php`,

```
 $username = $_POST["username"];
 $gender = $_POST['gender'];
 <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="gender" id="gender" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>">
```

Comment: But it gives me this error:                                                                                        
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\Test2.php on line 16

Comment: the problem above solved but how's about the skipped page? Thanks

Comment: just write the target in `action`,don't use `onclick` change it

Comment: Is it like that:<input type="submit" value="Proceed" target="example.php">?

Comment: No no no,i mean the form's action.

Test2.php:

`<form action="Test3.php" method="POST">`